# Leaflet removing/updating a legend

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I've read the posts on how to remove a legend from a leaflet map but still not having any luck.  I have a legend which I'd like to link to a time-slider that is indexed by year.   I'd like to have to legend display whatever year the time-slider is on.  Here is my function to create the legend:

```
function createLegend3(map, index){


var legendControl = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'bottomright'
    },
    onAdd: function(map){
       //create the container with a class name
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend-control-container');

        container.innerHTML += index
        //create temporal legend
        return container;
    }
});
// //add the legendControl to map
map.addControl(new legendControl); 
return legendControl;
```

};

As mentioned, I have a separate time-slider function in which user can scroll the different years with a time-slider (range-slider).  My idea (not, efficient, I know), was to call the createLegend3 for each year, using the index as a parameter:

```
if (index == 1971) {
                createLegend3(map, index)

if (index == 1972) {
                createLegend3(map, index)
```

The problem is that the map simply adds a NEW legend every time instead of updating.  Is there either a way to simply remove the existing legend and add another so that only one is displayed at a time?  Or a more efficient way to update the legend based on the value of the index in the time slider?  Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are only adding legends. If you want to replace it, you should remove the added legend first using `L.Map`'s `removeControl` method. A better way to do it is not to do the entire remove, create, add cycle but add a method to your L.Control which simply updates the innerHTML of your container. Then you can simply call `map.legend.setContent` and be done with it.

```js
L.Legend = L.Control.extend({
    'onAdd': function (map) {

        // add reference to mapinstance
        map.legend = this;

        // create container
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend-control-container');

        // if content provided
        if (this.options.content) {

            // set content
            container.innerHTML = this.options.content;

        }
        return container;
    },
    'onRemove': function (map) {

      // remove reference from mapinstance
      delete map.legend;

    },

    // new method for setting innerHTML
    'setContent': function(str) {
        this.getContainer().innerHTML = str;
    }
});

new L.Map('leaflet', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0
}).addControl(new L.Legend({
    'position': 'topright',
    'content': new Date  
})).on('click', function (e) {

    // use reference on mapinstance
    this.legend.setContent(new Date);

});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 1.0.3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi iH8, Thanks for your reply!  I ran your code but still can't get any legend to show up.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do I need some initial call like:                                            this.legend.addTo(map)

Comment: Without you sharing an example on JSFiddle or Plunker which shows clearly what goes wrong i'm in the dark here and would be just guessing. Why not fork my plunker and change it to what you're doing and post it here?